# Make Node server.js file safer by removing security information

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a public git[hub] project, and am now ready to switch it from development to production.  We are in the research field, so we like to share our code too!

I have a `server.js` file that we start with `node server.js` like most tutorials.
In it, there is connection information for the SQL server, and the location of the HTTPS certificates. It looks something like this:

```
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var ... = require('...');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

var Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
                        // ('database', 'username', 'password');
  sequelize = new Sequelize('db',       'uname',    'pwd', {
    logging: function () {}, 
    dialect: 'mysql',
    …
  });
…
var secureServer = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./location/to/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./location/to/server.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('./location/to/ca.crt'),
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}, app).listen('8443', function() {
    var port = secureServer.address().port;
    console.log('Secure Express server listening at localhost:%s', port);
});
```

In PHP you can have the connection information in another file, then import the files (and therefore variables) into scope to use.  Is this possible for the SQL connection (db, uname, pwd) and the file locations of the certs (just to be safe) so that we can commit the `server.js` file to git and ignore/not follow the secret file?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in a lot of different ways. One would be to use environment variables like `MYSQL_USER=foo MYSQL_PASSWD=bar node server.js` and then use `process.env.MYSQL_USER` in the code.

You can also read from files as you have suggested. You can do `require("config.json")` and node will automatically parse and import the JSON as JavaScript constructs. You can then `.gitignore` `config.json` and perhaps provide an `example.config.json`.

If you want to support both of these at once there is at least one library that allows you to do this simply: [`nconf`](https://github.com/indexzero/nconf).

Comment: I second `nconf`. You can chain config files together along with the `env` variables and they'll simply overwrite, if necessary. If a file isn't there, it will just move on to the next statement. See here for a detailed writeup I posted on a similar question using Azure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501641/deploy-azure-web-app-with-private-credentials-via-git/32510374#32510374

Comment: Usually I take all such variables directly from `process.env.*` and use `node-env-file` npm module to set them on development.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just store the configuration information in a JSON file. Node natively supports JSON files. You can simply require it:

```
var conf = require('myconfig.json');

var key = fs.readFileSync(conf.ssl_keyfile);
```

There are also 3rd party libraries for managing JSON config files that add various features. I personally like [config.json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config.json) because it allows you to publish a sample config file with empty values then, without modifying the sample config file, you can override those values using a `.local.json` file. It makes it easier to deal with config files in repos and also makes it easier to publish changes to the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [great writeup](http://12factor.net/) about how you should organise your deployments

Basically all application critical variables like db password, secret keys, etc., should be accessible via environment variables.

You could do something like this

```
// config.js
const _ = require('lodash');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

const config = {
  default: {
    mysql: {
      poolSize: 5,
    },
  },

  development: {
    mysql: {
      url: 'mysql://localhost/database',
    },
  },

  production: {
    mysql: {
      url: process.env.DB_URI,
    },
  },
};

module.exports = _.default(config.default, config[env]);

// app.js
const config = require('./config');
// ....
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.mysql.url);
```

Code is not perfect, but should be enough to get the idea.